# Поиск по регулярный выражениям в ElasticSearch

Tags: регулярные-выражения, поиск, elasticsearch, поисковые-системы

Возникла такая проблема, не могу понять, почему в elasticsearch не проходит поиск по регулярным выражениям. 
Запрос такой:

```
array(
      "index" => "catalog",
      "type" => "products",
      "body" => array(
          "query" => array(
              "regexp" => array(
                  "title" => array(
                      "value" => utf8("samsung.*s8")                                   
                   )
              )
          )
      )
```

При этом исходная строка имеет вид "Samsung G950F Galaxy S8 (жёлтый топаз)"
Т.е., по логике, код должен её видеть, т.к. при запросе со строкой "samsung.*" - он выводит все поля, но когда пытаешь указать явно на содержание подстроки "s8" или любой другой (ВАЖНЫЙ МОМЕНТ), которая отделена от основного слова пробелом, то данный код перестает искать. Может, в elastic есть какой-то специфический символ означающий "пробел"?

Результат var_dump:

```
array (size=4)
  'took' => int 2
  'timed_out' => boolean false
  '_shards' => 
array (size=3)
  'total' => int 1
  'successful' => int 1
  'failed' => int 0
  'hits' => 
array (size=3)
  'total' => int 0
  'max_score' => null
  'hits' => 
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено:
Оказалось нужно заменить запрос на такой формат:

```
array(
        "query" => array(
            "filtered" => array(
                "query" => array(
                    "simple_query_string" =>
                        array(
                            "query" => $sQuery,
                            "fields" => array("title^5", "tags"),
                            "default_operator" => "and",
                        ),
                )
            ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Самая большая беда:

*The Lucene regular expression engine is not Perl-compatible but supports a smaller range of operators.*

И попробуйте вот так:

```
curl -XGET 'server:9200/catalog/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{ "query": { "match":{ "title": { "query": "samsung ultra", "operator":"and" }}}}'
```

т.е. в запросе не надо указывать regexp, а использовать match и and

Comment: Да это тоже не то. Изначально запрос был таким:
"query" => array(
                            "multi_match" => array(
                                "query" => $q,
                                "operator" => "and",
                                "fields" => array("title", "tags"),
                                "type"      => "phrase_prefix"
                            )
                        )

Comment: Тут дело в том, что анализатор делит предложение на слова, в итоге он соответственно не может проверить всю строку "Samsung galaxy s8" на совпадение по запросу "samsung.*s8.*", Так как есть "samsung", "galaxy", "s8" по отдельности. 
Но ваше предложение не подходит т.к. в списке товаров есть товар "Samsung S850 Silver" фотокамера. И нужно именно регуляркой проверять. И кстати по такому запросу он вообще не находи samsung galaxy s8. Видимо приоритет идет на то, что в "Samsung S850 Silver", подстрока "s8" находится ближе чем в "samsung galaxy s8"

Comment: Ну может я что-то не так понял из задачи... Я поэкспериментировал с вашими названиями `"Samsung G950F Galaxy S8"`, `"Samsung UE49MU6100 Ultra HD 49"` и `"Samsung S850 Silver"`. Запрос {"query": { "match":{ "title": { "query": "samsung s8", "operator":"and" }}}} выдает мне только `"Samsung G950F Galaxy S8"`, а чтобы найти модель S850, я должен спросить так: `{"query": { "match":{ "title": { "query": "samsung s850", "operator":"and" }}}}`. Но если все таки нужно именно регуляркой, то я затрудняюсь.